# How to add a foreign key constraint references to the IS-A-to-Two-Tables relationship?

Tags: sql, t-sql, specialization, generalization

First in my ER-Model I have an **account** entity which has a **IS-A** relationship with two disjoint subentities **saving-account** and **checking-account**.
However I have a customer entity have a **depositor** relationship with the **account** entity, such the use case like the ER diagram below.

[image]

Therefore I translate the ER into the table like this:

customer(**cid**, cname)

depositor(**cid**, **account-number**)

saving-account(**account-number**, balance, interest-rate)

checking-account(**account-number**, balance, overdraft-amount)

So finally, I take only **two** tables saving-account and checking-account from the IS-A relationship.

---

Then the problem occurs, to create the depositor table, I take a T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE depositor(
    customer_id         int             not null,
    account_number      int             not null,
    access_date         Date            DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    PRIMARY KEY(customer_id, account_number),
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id)    REFERENCES customer(customer_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(account_number) REFERENCES account(account_number)
)
```

> At the final line, the foreign key **account_number** should reference to the **account** table, but what I have are **saving-account** and **checking-account** tables. In this situation, how do I add a constraint in T-SQL? Is it possible to add a constraint if I only take two tables from the IS-A relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have an extra table called `account`. Then `saving-account` and `checking-account` should be separate tables pointing to that.

Also, you should have an account_id field as a PK instead of account_number. As a best practice rule, PK should not have any business meaning, it should be an abstract concept.

In summary, I suggest following tables:

```
account(aid, account-number, balance, plus any other common field for account)
saving-account([optional pk], aid_ref, interest-rate, plus fields specific to saving-account)
checking-account([optional pk], aid_ref, overdraft-amount, plus fields specific to saving-account)
customer(cid, cname)
depositor(cid, aid)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to achieve that without having an account table in T-SQL?

Comment: No. Foreign key can not be conditional